# Display Selected row from mysql. (GridView)

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview

[image]

I have a gridview like this. I want to show only group_id and groups row. How can I achieve that?

Here is my code:

```
conn.Open();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM groups WHERE user_id = '" + current_user + "'", conn);
MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds);
GroupGrid.DataSource = ds;
GroupGrid.DataBind();
```

Comment: Note : `group_id and groups` are `columns` not `rows` here in the given image,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So when you use `SELECT * FROM groups` it would select/fetch all the column of the table. and thus you can only select/fetch the columns which you are desired to show.

Instead of `SELECT * FROM groups` you should be using `SELECT group_id, groups FROM groups` will solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

You can handle it with C# Code even you selected all columns from your table

```
                GroupGrid.DataSource = Nothing
                GroupGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = False
                GroupGrid.Columns(0).Name = "group_id"
                GroupGrid.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Group ID"
                GroupGrid.Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "group_id"


                GroupGrid.Columns(1).Name = "groups"
                GroupGrid.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Group"
                GroupGrid.Columns(1).DataPropertyName = "groups"

                GroupGrid.DataSource = ds;
                GroupGrid.DataBind();
```